# How to get alphabet string out of dataframe factor

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (`df`). The data frame has n columns. Each columns contains numbers, different signs and one or more or non names (alphabet characters). I would like to get the variable names for each dataframe column (which is a factor). I used the following command to extract from specific column, but it works only partially:

```
str_extract(paste0(df$V3, collapse=""), perl("(?<=\\|)[A-Za-z]+(?=\\|)"))
```

Here is the example for some columns (df is the dataframe and V1...Vn are its columns).

```
> df$V1
 [1] MSTV |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    MSTV |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |   
[25] |    |    |    |    |    |   
Levels: | MSTV
> df$V2
 [1]      MLTV MLTV |    |    |    |    |    |         DP   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    DP  
[25] |    |    |    |    |    |   
Levels:  | DP MLTV
> df$V3
 [1] <=             ASTV |    |    |    |    ASTV >    <=   ALTV ALTV |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    >   
[25] DP   |    |    |    |    DP  
Levels:  | <= > ALTV ASTV DP
> cleaned.df$V4
 [1] 0.4 <=  >       b   b   |   |       0.4 0           FM  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   FM  0   <=  UC  UC  |   |   >  
Levels:  | <= > 0 0.4 b FM UC
```

For `df$V1` I would like to get: MSTV
For `df$V2` I would like to get: DP MLTV
For `df$V3` I would like to get: ALTV ASTV DP
For `df$V4` I would like to get: b FM UC
and so on...

Comment: Have you tried with `lapply` i.e `lapply(df,  function(x) str_extract(paste0(x, collapse=""), "(?<=\\|)[A-Za-z]+(?=\\|)") )`

Comment: In your pattern `"(?<=\\|)[A-Za-z]+(?=\\|)"` you imply that you want alpha characters bordered by pipes. But in your expected output, you say you want matches bordered by different characters. It looks like you want `unique(unlist(str_extract_all(x, "[A-Za-z]+")))` for each row. Wrap that in lapply as akrun showed.

Comment: Or something like `lapply(df, function(x) grep("[a-zA-Z]+", levels(x), value = TRUE)`  Just take the levels to cut down on time

Comment: akrun, I tried lapply(df, function(x) str_extract(paste0(x, collapse=""), "(?<=\\|)[A-Za-z]+(?=\\|)") )  but it works only for V1 and V2 not for V3